# Number of arguments in macro

Tags: c, macros

I am writing a "mapping macro" and want to use it to generate enums, classes, function calls ...

This is how the macro looks like:

```
#define MY_MAPPING(ENTRY)                                   \
ENTRY(a,                    {0x10,0x01,0x01,0x00}, foo) \
ENTRY(b,                    {0x10,0x01,0x02,0x00}, boo)
```

Now I am trying to generate an enumeration using the "mapping macro"

```
#define STRCONC(a,b) a##b
#define EXPAND_TO_ENUM(a,b,c) STRCONC(a,_Idx),

typedef enum
{
    MY_MAPPING(EXPAND_TO_ENUM)
}example_Enum;
```

I am getting the error: `macro "EXPAND_TO_ENUM" passed 6 arguments, but takes just 3`. 
The reason is the elements between brackets, the compiler is considering each element into the bracket as a single element Why and do you have any Idea to solve the problem?

Of course using parentheses will solve the problem but I don't want to use them since I need to use the elements between brackets as function arguments after  for `foo` and `boo`, they are accepting array as input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am getting the error: macro "EXPAND_TO_ENUM" passed 6 arguments, but takes just 3. The reason is the elements between brackets, the compiler is considering each element into the bracket as a single element Why

Macros are processed by the *preprocessor*, not the "language proper".  A function-like macro invocation recognizes string-boundaries and will match parentheses, but not braces or square brackets... to the preprocessor, `[`, `{`, `}`, and `]` are just tokens having nothing to do with each other.  (Incidentally, the name for the thing you're writing is an X-macro).

When you invoke `MY_MAPPING(something)`, assuming that `something` "expands" to a token that's `#define`'d as a function-like macro, then once this part is evaluated:

*ENTRY*`(a, {0x10,0x01,0x01,0x00}, foo)`

...it will be a macro invocation with six arguments:

- `a`
- `{0x10`
- `0x01`
- `0x01`
- `0x00}`
- `foo`

> do you have any Idea to solve the problem?

Part 1 of the solution: Use parentheses.  If you use parentheses (the preprocessor *does* match those):

*ENTRY*`(a, (0x10, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00), foo)`

...then your invocation has three arguments:

- `a`
- `(0x10, 0x01, 0x10, 0x00)`
- `foo`

Part 2 is implied:

> they are accepting array as input.

...but I can't figure out what you're really saying here, other than that somehow you want that argument 2 to be surrounded by braces.  That you can do easily enough:

```
#define MY_MAPPING(ENTRY)                               \
ENTRY(a,                    (0x10,0x01,0x01,0x00), foo) \
ENTRY(b,                    (0x10,0x01,0x02,0x00), boo)
#define BRACIFY(...) { __VA_ARGS__ }
#define MAKE_SOME_INT_ARRAY_THINGY(ID, INIT, X) int ID[] = BRACIFY INIT;
MY_MAPPING(MAKE_SOME_INT_ARRAY_THINGY)
```

...expands to:

```
int a[] = { 0x10,0x01,0x01,0x00 }; int b[] = { 0x10,0x01,0x02,0x00 };
```

Comment: To clarify, the key part is `BRACIFY INIT`, which "gets rid of the parentheses" by passing the entire 2nd argument as a parenthesized list of arguments to the `BRACIFY` macro.